# Convert Charfield to string in Python

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I would like to be able to save line breaks in a PostgreSQL database with Python, but when retrieving the saved and printing it in console or sending it as context to a template (I am developing a project in Django), the line breaks are not applied.

```
>>> from apps.prestamos.models import Aprobado
>>> model = Aprobado.objects.last()
>>> print('First comment \n Second comment')
First comment
Second comment
>>> print(model.notas)
First comment \n Second comment
>>> print(str(model.notas))
First comment \n Second comment
>>>
```

The information is usually added from the client via POST.

```
....
model.notas = request.POST['notas']
model.save()
```

'request.POST' is a dictionary.

Comment: Can you show us how you're adding it to the database?

Comment: I updated the question with the detail you mention.

Comment: I suspect your problem is that the newline is encoded in `request.POST`, and not in retrieving the data from the database.

Comment: How can I decode the 'request.POST'?

Comment: Well are you literally typing the `\n` in the input from the client? You actually need to add a new line there (i.e. actually press the enter key)... Also HTML doesn't render newlines by default you will find plenty of duplicate questions for that part.

Comment: When the client saves the comment by pressing a button I add the date at the beginning of the text string and add "\n" at the end of the text with javascript before sending the information to the server via AJAX.

Comment: So can we see the javascript code that does this?

Answer (score 0):

can you please check the version of Django and Python it is latest or not.

I ran below code with python==3.8 and Django==3.2.6

```
>>> from core.models import Inspector
>>> ins = Inspector.objects.last()
>>> ins.address
```

o/p:-
'the \n new-line \n testing'

```
>>> print(ins.address)
```

o/p:-
the
new-line
testing

[please check the screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loSrO.png)